# Accessing object's properties via array index

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a situation where i have to programmatically do database inserts. I have multiple tables but the order of information of those tables are similar , i.e, in each table, the first coulmn in id, and second is a foregin key, and third is a name, and fourth is a blob and fifth is a text.

I searched [php doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php) and found that I can use $objectName[index] to access the database property. I am getting error

`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\....php on line ..` .

The erroneous line is indicated on the code

```
private function uploadTemp($databaseObject, $table_name){
    $this->load->database();
    //get file_contents too;
    $file_id = $databaseObject[3]; // < Here's where the error appeared
    $this->db->from('tbl_file')->where('file_id',$file_id); 
    $q = $this->db->get();
    $data = $q->row();
    $query = "INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES(NULL, '".$databaseObject[2]."','".$data->filecontent."');";
    $this->db->query($query);
}
```

I am using CodeIgniter as a framework.

Comment: Isn't it the line before the marked one, i.e. `$file_id = $databaseObject[3];` that triggers the error?

Comment: @VolkerK The second line trigged that! That made be surprised!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try casting to array:

```
$file_id = (array) $databaseObject[3];
```

As STDClass is just a dummy container with `public dynamic variables` and `no methods`, there should be no problems in casting it to array and backwards as well.

However in some situations numbers are used to represent a variable name.

Example:

```
$array ; //Is some array created by engines / database handlers.

$obj = (object) $array ;

echo $obj->0 ; //Hell it will not work.
echo $obj[0] ; //The same problem.

echo $obj->{'0'} ; //PERFECT
```

Comment: What if you try: `$file_id = $databaseObject->{'3'};` ?

Comment: Actually my database object had different identifiers depending upon cases, but had the same kind of data in the third position! And I was trying to get the third data. I guess the method is same!

Comment: IMO it is a really wrong stuff that CodeIgniter encases data into objects. Objects must contain properties with real names. Arrays must contain sets of data and be number-indexed usually.

Answer (score 1):

try this function [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)()

or create function to convert to array

```
function array_to_object($array)//from CodeIgniter forum
 {
  return (is_array($array)) ? (object) array_map(__FUNCTION__, $array) : $array;
 }
```